# How to retract attributes in Datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic

i've created a set of attributes in the Datomic schema. Their :db/idents are grouped into three namespaces: :name, :tree, :node. Now i want to delete all of these and start fresh. I've found all of the required attributes:

```
(def results 
  (q '[:find ?e 
       :where [?e :db/ident ?v]
              [(namespace ?v) ?res]
              [(contains? #{"task", "node", "tree"} ?res)]
     ] 
     (db conn)))
```

Then created a set of retractEntity statements:

```
(def retract-statements 
  (into [] (map #(vector :db.fn/retractEntity (first %1)) results)))
```

And now i'm trying to invoke the transaction:

```
@(d/transact conn [retract-statements])
```

It gives me:
:db.error/invalid-attribute Schema change must be followed by :db.install/attribute or :db.alter/attribute

Apparently i'm doing something wrong. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are your vectors nested too much? Do you need to do `@(d/transact conn retract-statements)`, instead of `@(d/transact conn [retract-statements]) - because retract-statements is already a vector of vectors. Just a thought...

Comment: I've just used (delete-database uri) and (create-database uri), which is perfectly fine for my purposes. It seems that there is no way to retract attributes - seems that the only feasible way to get rid of all attributes is by renaming. Is that a correct statement?

Comment: Yep I think you're right https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/datomic/7-9lUE9Nm4k/fOhAvt-gyOIJ

Comment: See [Retract  Datomic](https://docs.datomic.com/cloud/tutorial/retract.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to directly retract attributes in Datomic. Once you install an attribute, it's around forever unless you delete the entire database. This makes sense, given that Datomic (except in the special case of excision) never truly deletes any data - if you could actually remove attributes, then data originally transacted against those attributes would not be retrievable.

Note that you *can* rename attributes, but that it still keeps its old ident as a synonym as well unless you repurpose it for something else.

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that you cannot retract schema you can retract everything about an attribute (everything about that attribute can be found via the AEVT index) and then mark that attribute as not to be used. For example, you can do this with the `:db/doc` string.

If you really want it just go away you can excise the attribute. You'll lose history if you do this but it will nuke the attribute from orbit. If you want to excise the attribute, make a database backup first because if you make a mistake with excision the **data is not recoverable**.